# Update the data in database in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

I can successfully select the data I want to update to another page and populate my text boxes but if I set the selected values to my textbox and then try to update it wouldn't work and the same data is shown in database table.

However if I DO NOT set those values to my textboxes, then I can successfully update which is not what I am after.

I would like the user to see the data and record that s being updated

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserClassesDataContext db= new UserClassesDataContext();

    var qr = from user in db.Users
             where user.user_id == new Guid(Request.QueryString["user_id"])
             select user;

    foreach (var q in qr)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = q.user_name;
        TextBox2.Text = q.password;
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserClassesDataContext db = new UserClassesDataContext();

    var qr = from user in db.Users
             where user.user_id == new Guid(Request.QueryString["user_id"])
             select user;

    foreach (var q in qr)
    {
        q.user_name = TextBox1.Text;
        q.password = TextBox2.Text;
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, when you submit the button, the code inside `Page_Load` event is executing again.That means it is reading the data from your table and setting the value to textboxes(thus overwriting what user updated via the form ) and you are updating your record with this values (original values). So basically you are updating the rows with same values.

You can use the `Page.IsPostBack` property to determine whether the event is occurred by a postback(button click) or initial page load.
This should fix it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    // to do: read and set to textbox here.
  }
}
```